# Transfrer file from raspberry pi to file server on same network with python

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, file-transfer, fileserver

I have a raspberry pi taking pictures, that is connected to the LAN. I want to automatically upload each picture file to a samba ubuntu file server I have on my network, so I can easily view them.

I have tried to get the command "curl" with no luck. (which I would run with subprocess in python)
This is my command that doesn't work (trying to copy test.png to destination directory):

`curl -T "/home/pi/Desktop/test.png" "smb://10.51.112.128/home/thomas/thomasdrive/destination" -u thomas:87651234`

I get:

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`

I've been searching the internet for a solution, but nothing I try seems to work

Comment: Why are you using `curl` with a Samba server? Why don't you *mount* a directory that the Samba server is exporting then simply save the picture in that directory?

Comment: The Samba server requires a username/password to access the files, so how would would I go about mounting?(sorry, I'm a beginner with linux, if you coudn't tell)

Comment: Have a look here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: Hey, thanks, after alot of trail and error I was able to get that to work. The only problem now is that when I try to modify the mounted folder in python i get:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`

Comment: Have a look for *"writeable Samba shares"*, e.g. https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Create+samba+share+writeable+by+all%2C+group%2C+or+only+a+user

Comment: I've been busy, sorry for the late reply
I finally got this command to work:
`sudo sshpass -p "87651234" scp '/home/pi/Desktop/test.png' thomas@10.51.112.128:/home/thomas/thomasdrive/destination`